# How to change image after animation complete in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I want to play animation only one time on click and  after  animation complete its image to be change. The problem is that animation remained in its one of the state which I defined thus showing image of the animation. Please help me I had searched everywhere but nothing workout.**I am beginner and this animation is very important**.

[image: Scrrenshot of Animation]

Comment: Could you post a picture of your animation states to have a better idea of what you mean? 

Please check here: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation/animator-controller

and here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/103611/unity-5-1-how-to-control-the-animation

and make sure those links can't help you first.

Comment: Basically I am making a dice game in that I used animation on dice image. But after roll animation dice do not change its image which i randomly generated and assigned to that sprite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a SpriteRenderer or Image is controlled by an animation it isn't possible to set the sprite manually, you have to use an animation. Make a new state with the single frame you want to display after the click. Then make a transition from the click state to the new state in your Animator. When the click animation has finished playing it will then go over to the other state and display the other image until you cause it to transition to click again.

For your specific case you need to setup one state per outcome that you want. So you would make one state for when the dice turns up a 1, one state for when it turns up a 2 etc. Then you use an [animation parameter](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationParameters.html) of type int to inform the animator of the outcome using [Animator.SetInteger](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetInteger.html). Your [transitions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Transition.html) would then have Conditions based on the number that the outcome state represents. So for the first state the condition would be "Animation parameter Equals 1".

Here is a visual aid:
[image]

Comment: Sir, I want  to change image which is randomly generated cannot be defined in any state.

Comment: This can be the solution of my project but not an answer because I finding a way to change an image after animation complete. using code:->  Image dice.image.sprite = dice1;

Comment: Like I mentioned in the opening sentence of my answer, that is not possible when using an Animator.

Comment: When I roll one more time than it won't change number because it keep remains in the the state of one of the outcome, how to resolve that. sorry for late response.

Comment: In the transition from "Any state" to "Roll" in my example you need to add the condition of "RollTrigger". Then you can make another roll by first calling: `diceAnimator.SetInteger("OutcomeValue", Random.Range(1, 7));` to get a new random value and then 
`diceAnimator.SetTrigger("RollTrigger");` to get back to the "Roll" state.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "State Machine Behaviours" and their "OnStateExit" method

```
public Animator Anim;

void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        //Play Animation On CLick
        Anim.Play("YourAnimation");
    }

}
```

On State Machine Behaviour(Add this behaviour to animation state in Animator)

```
override public void OnStateExit(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
{
    //Change Sprite Code
}
```

See

- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/StateMachineBehaviour.html
- https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/5-pre-order-beta/state-machine-behaviours

Comment: For this I need to have another class which is inheriting StateMachineBehaviour?

Comment: Yeah click on animator and there is add behaviour option click on that then you will have statemachine behaviour script

Answer (score 0):

You can override the Animator's control on the sprite by setting the sprite in `LateUpdate()`. The simplest, but perhaps not the most efficient, way of going about this would be:

1. Add an animation event to the end of your animation which calls a function. Let's call it `AnimationComplete()`.
2. Inside of `AnimationComplete()`, set a flag.
3. Inside of `LateUpdate()`, check if the flag is set. If it is, then change your sprite.

   ```
   public Sprite mySprite;
   public GameObject myObject;
   bool animationIsComplete = false;

   void LateUpdate()
   {
       if(animationIsComplete)
       {
           myObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = mySprite;
       }
   }

   //Called via animation event
   public void AnimationComplete()
   {
       animationIsComplete = true;
   }
   ```

Comment: When to call this method AnimationComplete?

Comment: Add an [animation event](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html) to the final frame of your animation and configure it to call `AnimationComplete()`. See the first screenshot in the link to understand how to add an event to your animation.  After that, select it, drag it to the last frame, and configure the function it calls in the inspector.